# Mysql-dev for mac os

Tags: mysql

I'm installing sphinx for my macbook pro but I failed when I ran "sudo make", it generate the following error.

error: mysql.h: No such file or directory.

I navigate throw the web searching for a solution & the solution was to setup mysql-devel.

The new problem is that I can't find it for mac?? what shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Fink package management system** to install mysql-dev. There is some getting started information [here](http://www.finkproject.org/help/index.php?phpLang=en) for fink. It may seem like a roundabout way to get things installed but in the long term it will pay dividends.

Good luck,

Chris