# Where to find mysql include files for configuring Sphinx on MAMP

Tags: sphinx

I tried to configure using `/.configure`
got the following error
can anyone tell me how to resolve this?? I'm unable to find mysql files and include folder in MAMP/Library

any help..

```
configuring Sphinx
------------------

checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads... none
checking for LIBS needed for pthreads... -lpthread
checking for pthreads... found
checking whether to compile with MySQL support... yes
checking for mysql_config... not found
checking MySQL include files... configure: error: missing include files.

******************************************************************************
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
   your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.
******************************************************************************
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483662/mysql-dev-for-mac-os

Comment: i'm trying with fink.. but unable to get the mysql :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MAMP is missing some mysql's library and include files that sphinx requires. You have to upgrade your MAMP by coping the required files to the `MAMP/Library/` directory.

1. Go to your `MAMP/Library` directory and create mysql directory:
2. Go to http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php and download the appropriated one. You could go to phpMyAdmin to check your MAMP's mysql version.
3. Untar it and copy the `include/` and `lib/` to the `MAMP/Library/mysql` you just created before.
4. In terminal, assuming your MAMP is located in `/Applications/`, then your configure should be like below:

   $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx --with-mysql-includes=/Applications/MAMP/Library/mysql/include --with-mysql-libs=/Applications/MAMP/Library/mysql/lib

I hope this helps. You can check out my [blog](http://quyennt.com/sphinx-open-source-fulltext-search-engine/) on this problem or let me know if you meet any other problems.

Comment: I tried this and when I downloaded: mysql-5.5.25a.tar.gz I didn't find a lib folder I did find libservices, libmysqld, and libmysql ... I'm going to try libmysql ...

Comment: @Mark Steudel I don't see what's your point, did you solve the problem? If not, please specify more detail so that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error what I did is i installed a mysql-devel that would fit my server of my case its mysql-devel.x86_64

```
  # yum install mysql-devel.x86_64
```

and then I run the ./configure with out mysql to disable mysql support for the meantime

```
  # ./configure --without-mysql
```

and It worked for me. I was able to get this at the end of the message

```
 generating configuration files
 ------------------------------

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating libstemmer_c/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating sphinx.conf.dist
config.status: creating sphinx-min.conf.dist
config.status: creating config/config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands

 configuration done
 ------------------

You can now run 'make install' to build and install Sphinx binaries.
On a multi-core machine, try 'make -j4 install' to speed up the build.

Updates, articles, help forum, and commercial support, consulting, training,
and development services are available at http://sphinxsearch.com/

Thank you for choosing Sphinx!
```

Hope it helped.